# Scoring system not adding up right when using enumerated types

Tags: c

This function is supposed to calculate the score of a blackjack hand. The kicker is that for aces when the score is less then 11 I want to add 10 if there is an ace, because I already have it = to 1 so it will just add one if the score is greater than 11, and for some reason mine is not doing that and I don't know why, it just adds 1. Heres my types and my function.

```
typedef enum { HEARTS, DIAMONDS, SPADES, CLUBS } suit_t;
typedef enum { ACE = 1, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING } value_t;

typedef struct {
    suit_t suit;
    value_t value;
} card_t;
typedef struct {
    card_t playercards[21];
    int num_cards_in_array;
} hand_t;
// blackjack_value = returns an integer that represents the blackjack value of the hand
int blackjack_value(hand_t hand) {
    int score = 0;
    int i;
    card_t card;

    for (i=0; i < hand.num_cards_in_array; i++) {
        score = points(hand.playercards[i]) + score;

    if (score < 11 && card.value == ACE) {
        score = score + points(hand.playercards[i])+ 10;
    }
    }
    return score;
}
```

Comment: This should be more like `if (score < 11 && any_card_was_an_ace)`

Comment: Well, you're missing your hand definition, your points function, and how you're calling this and determining the value is incorrect. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and see if you can come up with a complete example.

Comment: You never set the `card` variable to anything

Comment: what would I set it equal to? I can't just set it to zero because the type  is card_t. @samgak

Comment: Do you actually need it at all? Why not just use `hand.playercards[i]`? However I think you need to rethink the whole logic of when you count an ace as 11. For example, if an ace being counted as 11 and a subsequent card puts the total over 21, the value should change back to 1

Comment: as chux suggested, set a flag if any card is an ace, and then at the end of the loop add 10 to the total if the flag is true and the total is less than (or equal to) 21

Comment: Okay I don't know how to do that. @samgak

Comment: function: `points()` not defined

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
if (score < 11 && card.value == ACE)
```

how is this expected to know which card is being looked at?  I think this is the root of your problem.

Suggest:

```
if( score < 11 && hand.playercards[i] == ACE )
```

However, shouldn't that check be after the loop that sums up the cards in the hand?